# nginx-extras ok for production server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, debian, web-server

I need the upload progress extension on my production server running Nginx, the only problem is that to do that I must actually recompile the whole of Nginx.

This means uninstalling the repo Nginx, installing from source (and all the maintenance that comes with it) and compiling with the module option pointing to the downloaded upload progress source.

I did however, find a less painful way of doing it by installing `nginx-extras` however this is the `-V` signature post-installation:

> configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx
>   --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/chunkin-nginx-module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module
>   --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit
>   --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-http-push --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-lua --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upload-module
>   --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress
>   --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
>   --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module

And I am slightly concerned that one of these extras could cause problems on a production server.

Does nginx work in such a way that if I do not include the options for the extensions in extras it won't use them or I won't notice them or should I go to the effort of manually compiling Nginx?

My initial test on my dev server tells me that these don't make too much visible changes until they're used but I am unsure if I am missing something.

Comment: Most of the modules I've used in nginx need actual changes to the nginx config to actually activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those modules set off any alarm bells for me. I wouldn't expect them to do much to the default behavior of nginx until you reference them from the nginx config and use them for something.